# How to convert database results to Dictionary<int, List<decimal>>

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

We have a table which returns the following rows:

```
ID (integer)   PRICE (decimal)
106                 5.2
106                 6.7
107                 9.2
107                 8.3
107                 3.2
```

I need to convert the values from this table to something like this:

```
106, (5.2, 6.7)
107, (9.2, 8.3, 3.2)
```

In this case this is `Dictionary<int, List<decimal>>`, but it does not have to be a dictionary. I can change it, if necessary.

Number of ID's and corresponding prices for them is not fixed (so we can have 108 in this list and it can have one or more prices).

The following is what I have done:

```
var retVal = new Dictionary<int, List<decimal>>();
var dbRow = new List<decimal>();
var itemsPerRow = new List<List<decimal>>();
```

....

```
//loop the table
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        dbRow.Add(int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString()));
        dbRow.Add(decimal.Parse(dr["PRICE"].ToString()));
        itemsPerRow.Add(dbRow);
    }        
}

//get the distinct ID's 
var gb = itemsPerRow.GroupBy(x => x[0]).Select(x => x.Key);

foreach (var row in gb)
{
    if (!retVal.ContainsKey((int) row))
    {
        IEnumerable<decimal> ratesForRow = itemsPerRow.Where(x => x.Contains(row)).Select(x => x[1]);
        retVal.Add((int) row, ratesForRow.ToList());
    }
}
```

This works but it seems not very straight forward, what I am not happy is that I am looping the database results, creating a list, then looping the list again, also my list is declared as to contain decimals but the ID column is int, so I am having to cast it to int. Is this OK, or is there another way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: "so we can have 108 in this list and it can have one or more prices)." This make no sense at all, you need a rule to distinguish values how can the product have multiple prices with no difference in product, you have no way to tell them apart. If you were storing  this in a DB the non-unique Integer would definitely not be the ID you would create a separate Identity ID field, but then if they were identical why would you store both?

Comment: You dont understand simple principle of an ID, an ID is unique. The ID is unique and a one to many-relation is needed, then a simple navigation property is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in one loop:

```
  Dictionary<int, List<Decimal>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<Decimal>>();

  using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      int id = int.Parse(reader["ID"].ToString());
      Decimal price = Decimal.Parse(reader["PRICE"].ToString());

      List<Decimal> list;

      if (result.TryGetValue(id, out list))    
        list.Add(price);
      else 
        result.Add(id, new List<Decimal> {price});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see. First, you only need **one list**:

```
var tempResults = Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<int, decimal>>().ToList();
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
while (dr.Read())
     tempResults.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, decimal> 
            { Key = int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString()), 
              Value = decimal.Parse(dr["PRICE"].ToString()) });
```

Then, the processing is reasonably simple.

```
return tempResults.GroupBy(k => k.Key).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: But, will this not give the key already exists in dictionary error when you try to insert the same ID as KEY?